# Помогите обдумать логику структуры базы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер, в общем собираюсь писать свой первый проект. Суть будет такая: посетителю выводится 2 товара, какой он считает лучшим - выбирает. Будет рейтинг товаров по каждой категории (продукты, овощи...).

На выбор пользователю нужно будет давать отфильтрованный товар, т.е. он сначала выбирает что категорию товаров.. затем из базы достаются 2 случайных товара по этой категории и он одну из них выбирает.

Также будет общий рейтинг, где можно будет фильтровать... и увидеть лучшие товары по каждой категории.

Теперь вот думаю, как бы базу составить.

Допустим есть 1 таблица с такими полями: id, имя товара, категория товара, допустим.. год производства товара, из какой страны товар.
Фильтровать по всем этим параметрам можно как и при выборе (выборе одно из двух товаров), так и при просмотре общего рейтинга.

Теперь вопрос: как-бы разумнее это составить, чтобы оптимизироавнно было? Держать всё в одной таблице или чтото перенести в другую и скрепить их?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

три таблицы

1. товары (id, название, год - если фиксирован, категория_id, производитель_id, страна_id)
2. категории товаров (id, название, родитель - если категории иерархические)
3. производители (id, название)
4. страны производители (id, название)

это справочники
плюс таблица, т.н. регистр, для рейтинга, данные по выбору посетителей. Например, поля: `дата_выбора, товар_id, предложен=1, выбран=(0,1)` - для подробной структуры периодически регламентом сворачивать это дело за период, будут записи вида: `дата_начала_периода, товар_id, предложен=x, выбран=y`...

Comment: ага, значит для каждого критерия своя таблица.. понял, спасибо  
  
а вот что вы тут имели ввиду, я, честно, не понял:  
это справочники плюс таблица, т.н. регистр, для рейтинга, данные по выбору посетителей  
  
это тоже:  
  
для подробной структуры периодически регламентом сворачивать это дело за период

Comment: ну рейтинг тоже ведь в базе будет храниться? значит для него нужно таблицу завести. структура примерно такая как написал. это простейший вариант рейтинга количество показов и количество выборов. возможно, структура будет не такая, все зависит от семантики рейтингов...

сворачивать это значит, что данных будет довольно много, чтобы база не росла сильно, ее можно сворачивать по товару было сто записей, делаем одну, суммируя результат. ну тоже зависит все от структуры рейтингов, это был просто пример.

Comment: теперь понятно, спасибо

Comment: А не правильнее-ли воспользоваться, например, ER-диаграммой и методами ее конструирования + НФ?

Какой смысл давать начинающему человеку придуманный (благодаря вашему опыту) вариант БД?

Comment: что за ER и НФ? :)

Comment: @Dex Без преумножения сущностей про ER (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER-модель_данных) и НФ (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальная_форма) описана простейшая достаточная структура базы, к которой человек придет все равно после нескольких лет обучения в универе или месяца гугления. 
Не вижу в этом криминала и достаточно смысла.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я больше все же имел ввиду, что какой смысл на вопро "как" отвечать "вот возьми, я уже сделал"